# Upload Files to Box from Linux Console using c# application

Tags: c#, mono, oauth-2.0, monodevelop, box-api

I have a **c# desktop application developed using Mono** which upload **files to Box**, In windows i am able to upload the files . The problem is that in windows there comes a **Box login page** and i manually giving the details and i got the code and token pair to upload file, but in **Linux console mode i am not able to display the Box login page**..

what should i do to Upload files to Box from Linux console.

i am using **box-csharp-sdk-v2**

Comment: How bare-bones stripped down is your Linux?  Do you not even have a browser?  Which browser is already on the machine?

Comment: i am using linux console mode

Comment: OAuth2 requires the initial login request to be made through a browser. Also, the officially supported sdk is located here: https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2

Answer (score 1):

You can forgo Box's APi entirely and hook something up to it via WebDAV, which is how it's traditionally done on console linux (well, that, and rsync). Since WebDAV is built on top of HTTP, it's cross platform as well. You'll need a C# friendly WebDAV client and all the settings/information to hook them up. Here's a quick link to a simple WebDAV client that should be easy enough to figure out:

[WebDAVClient @ Github](https://github.com/kvdb/WebDAVClient/blob/master/WebDAVClient/WebDAVClient.cs)

Point it at https://www.box.com/dav with your Box email and login, and voilà!

(Another, even simpler alternative is to set up DAVFS2 accordingly, making sure the drive is mounted, then handling it like any other directory. However, this requires outside setup and takes control out of the app's hands.)